# Why does this pop-up keep asking for the location of different programs?

Tags: macos, mac, monterey

Recently a pop-up has been appearing asking for the location of different programs e.g, Brave, Microsoft Edge, Vivaldi - all of which I'm pretty sure I've not used on my Mac. When I click on the window to see which application is causing the pop-up, the application name in the menu bar doesn't change no matter which application is in focus. It floats on top of other applications so I'm presuming it's the OS.

I've attached a screenshot. I'm using a MacBook Air M1 with OS 12.1. This behaviour may have started when I upgraded to 12.1 last month.

[image]

Comment: I've never seen such a window, but could find some (very old) references to something similar here: https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/38531/wireshark-doesnt-find-x11-xquartz-277/ and here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3190157 Brave, Edge and Vivaldi are all web browsers, have you noticed a pattern when this window appears (for example, after visiting a web site or opening a specific app, or after pressing a certain key shortcut)? When the window appears, do you see a symbol for Shortcuts (two stacked squares) or Automator (a cogwheel) in the menu bar?

Comment: @jaume I have two Shortcut shortcuts: i) to close all apps, ii) to open a list of apps. After reading your comment, I ran both shortcuts and noticed that the window in question pops up after running the 'open apps' shortcut. However, the only apps I have listed for the shortcut to open are Google Chrome, Spike (email), Microsoft To-Do, Calendar (Apple), Music (Apple), and Safari.